# Custom JSX to React intl formattedMessage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a string which has a link inside. However, I cannot brake the string for translation purposes so I thought that by using 'FormattedMessage' I could pass some JSX into it like so:

```
    <FormattedMessage
        id= "CreateIdentity.error.generalError"
        values={link}
    />
```

where link is:

```
const link = 
    <Link target="_blank" to={`${config.help}`}>
        {formatMessage({id: "CreateIdentity.error.linkHelpPages"})}
    </Link>;
```

where my translation string is:

```
  "CreateIdentity.error.generalError": "You can try again, or {link} for more information";
```

Full component:

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import Link from 'react-router';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import FormattedMessage from 'react-intl';

import {Alert} from '../Icons/Icons';

import {getFullConfig} from '../../../utils/getFullConfig';

const config = getFullConfig();

const GenericError = (props) => {
    const {formatMessage, statusCode} = props;
    const link = 
        <Link target="_blank" to={`${config.help}`}>
            {formatMessage({id: "CreateIdentity.error.linkHelpPages"})}
        </Link>;


    return (
        <Fragment>
            <header>
                {formatMessage({id: "CreateIdentity.error.generalErrorTitle"})}
            </header>
            <Alert className="alert" />
            {/* {formatMessage({id: "CreateIdentity.error.generalError"}, {link})} */}


            <FormattedMessage
                id= "CreateIdentity.error.generalError"
                values={{link}}
            />
            <p>
                {formatMessage({id: "CreateIdentity.error"})}
                {statusCode}
            </p>
        </Fragment>
    );
};


GenericError.propTypes = {
    formatMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    statusCode: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};

export default GenericError;
```

however the application the breaks:

> index.js?92df:697 [React Intl] Error formatting message:
>   "CreateIdentity.error.generalError" for locale: "en" Error: The intl
>   string context variable 'link' was not provided to the string 'You can
>   try again, or {link} for more information'

Comment: The syntax of your translation string is certainly incorrect. You need to use a template literal to format a string with a variable. You may also consider setting it to some JSX depending on how your `FormattedMessage` component is written.